# combining 2 javascript that works seperatly to send realtime data to websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm building a robot based on a raspberry pi. I'm currently working on the controling part.

I found 2 seperate scripts that work fine on their own, but I cannot seems to find a way to build what I want with these scripts.

Here's what I want. I want to control my robot with a soft joystick (see code for the joystick lower) The code for the joystick works perfectly as it draw a joystick and return the X and Y value in real time to the browser.

Now what I would like is to send these values to my server using websocket. I installed a websocket server in python on my server and it is receiving values from an example script that I found.

So I'd like to be able to pass the values from the joystick to the websocket server.

Any hint would be appreciated

Here is the joystick part

```
    <html>
    <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

    <style>
    body {
        overflow    : hidden;
        padding     : 0;
        margin      : 0;
        background-color: #BBB;
    }
    #info {
        position    : absolute;
        top     : 0px;
        width       : 100%;
        padding     : 5px;
        text-align  : center;
    }
    #info a {
        color       : #66F;
        text-decoration : none;
    }
    #info a:hover {
        text-decoration : underline;
    }
    #container {
        width       : 100%;
        height      : 100%;
        overflow    : hidden;
        padding     : 0;
        margin      : 0;
        -webkit-user-select : none;
        -moz-user-select    : none;
    }
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
        <label id="conn_text"></label><br />
    <div id="messages_txt" /></div> 
    <div id="info">

        Touch the screen and move
        -
        works with mouse too as debug
        <br/>
        <span id="result"></span>

     </div> 
    <script src="virtualjoystick.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.log("touchscreen is", VirtualJoystick.touchScreenAvailable() ? "available" : "not available");

        var joystick    = new VirtualJoystick({
            container   : document.getElementById('container'),
            mouseSupport    : true,
                            //stationaryBase: true,
                            baseX: 200,
                            baseY: 200,
                    limitStickTravel: true,
                    stickRadius: 100


        });
        joystick.addEventListener('touchStart', function(){
            console.log('down')
        })
        joystick.addEventListener('touchEnd', function(){
            console.log('up')
        })
        setInterval(function(){
            var outputEl    = document.getElementById('result');

            outputEl.innerHTML  = '<b>Result:</b> '
                + ' dx:'+joystick.deltaX()
                + ' dy:'+joystick.deltaY()
                + (joystick.right() ? ' right'  : '')
                + (joystick.up()    ? ' up'     : '')
                + (joystick.left()  ? ' left'   : '')
                + (joystick.down()  ? ' down'   : '')   
        }, 1/30 * 1000);
        setInterval(function(){
            var message = joystick.deltaX();
            ws.send(message);
        }, 1/30 * 1000);


    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is the socket part

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Websocket</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Websocket</h1>
    <label id="conn_text"></label><br />
    <input type="text" id="input_text"/>
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="Send" /><br />
    <div id="messages_txt" />
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  //change example.com with your IP or your host
  var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.2.35:8888/ws");
  ws.onopen = function(evt) {
  var conn_status = document.getElementById('conn_text');
  conn_status.innerHTML = "Connection status: Connected!"
  };
  ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
  var newMessage = document.createElement('p');
  newMessage.textContent = "Server: " + evt.data;
  document.getElementById('messages_txt').appendChild(newMessage);
  };
  ws.onclose = function(evt) {
  alert ("Connection closed");
  };
  $("#button").click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var message = $("#input_text").val();
  ws.send(message);
  var newMessage = document.createElement('p');
  newMessage.textContent = "Client: " + message;

document.getElementById('messages_txt').textContent=newMessage.textContent;
});
});
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the script where

```
 var message = joystick.deltaX();
               ws.send(message);
```

is contained within `load` event handler

```
window.onload = function() {
          console.log("touchscreen is", VirtualJoystick.touchScreenAvailable() ? "available" : "not available");

    var joystick    = new VirtualJoystick({
        container   : document.getElementById('container'),
        mouseSupport    : true,
                        //stationaryBase: true,
                        baseX: 200,
                        baseY: 200,
                limitStickTravel: true,
                stickRadius: 100


    });

    joystick.addEventListener('touchStart', function(){
        console.log('down')
    });
    joystick.addEventListener('touchEnd', function(){
        console.log('up')
    });
    var outputEl = document.getElementById('result');
    setInterval(function(){

        outputEl.innerHTML  = '<b>Result:</b> '
            + ' dx:'+joystick.deltaX()
            + ' dy:'+joystick.deltaY()
            + (joystick.right() ? ' right'  : '')
            + (joystick.up()    ? ' up'     : '')
            + (joystick.left()  ? ' left'   : '')
            + (joystick.down()  ? ' down'   : '')   
    }, 1/30 * 1000);
    setInterval(function(){
        var message = joystick.deltaX();
        ws.send(message);
    }, 1/30 * 1000);

}
```

or use `.ready(function() {})`.

```
$(function() {/* joystick stuff here */})
```

`var outputEl = document.getElementById('result');` may not be defined when the assignment is attempted.

Also, it is not necessary to re-define `outputEl` at each `setInterval()` call. You can define the variable outside `setInterval` call.